# AngularJS - How to get offset of top and left position of an element in document

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

looking for guru help,
I'm using angularJS in a repeating list in the code below. How would I get the the absoulute position or relative to the document of the top and left offset position for 'div class="section"' and print it in the console?
Is it it possible with AngularJs or do I need to use Jquery?

Ultimately my goal is get the offset positions and use it to position a modal window, but if I could get help on the above I should be able to figure the rest out.

My code is below and thanks in advance:

**HTML**

```
<body ng-controller="MyMgtCtrl">
    <div class="container-fluid" >
        <div class="section">{{gapSection.headerID}}.{{gapSection.sectionID}}</div>
        <label ng-click="showMenu()" class="label label-primary">Toggle</label>
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</body>
```

**Angular Controller**

```
var myMgtApp = angular.module("myMgtApp");

myMgtApp.controller("MyMgtCtrl",function($scope){
    var data={
        showMenu:false,
        gapSection:[{headerID:1,sectionID:1,requirement:"SOME DATA 1"},
        {headerID:2,sectionID:1,requirement:"SOME DATA"},
        {headerID:2,sectionID:2,requirement:"SOME DATA 3"}]
    };

    $scope.data = data;
    $scope.gapSection = data.gapSection;
    $scope.showMenu=function($scope){
        data.showMenu=!data.showMenu;
    };
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inside `ng-click`, you get an `$event` object you can pass to your method.

```
<label ng-click="showMenu($event)" class="label label-primary">Toggle</label>
```

The event has two properties `pageX` and `pageY`, which may be what you want.

```
$scope.showMenu=function(passedEventObject){
    var x = passedEventObject.pageX;
    var y = passedEventObject.pageY;
    data.showMenu=!data.showMenu;
};
```

Check the "Arguments" section of the [`ng-click`documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick).

Then click through to [the `$event` page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-), which says

> The object is an instance of a [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) when jQuery is present **or a similar jqLite object**. Once you get this, Angular role is over and it's a jQuery / DOM question.

(highlight mine)

The [jQuery Event Object](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) shows the two properties.

**Update:**

This will give you X and Y of the mouse, which is pretty relevant for your use case of modal positioning on click as, however, to be more accurate, you can try other things:

```
var position = $event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = position.left;
var y = position.top;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. However looking through the details I believe pageX and pageY is only for the mouse cursor position. Is it possible to get the position of a particular element eg the div class="section" in my code?

Comment: That's right. You might check if `$event` has `target` as native DOM element, if so, the updated to the answer might work (if it's jqLite element, just add `[0]` to get the DOM object).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you very much this works very well for the exact position for the label, and best of all it is very clean. One further question to elaborate it, is it possible to tranverse to the parent or previous element on the $event?  I tried using .parent() and .prev() but got an error

Comment: Once you get the target, it's a DOM element. You can use native DOM properties or wrap it Angular element (jqLite element) like `angular.element($event.target)`. Most likely the DOM properties like `parentNode` etc will be all you want.

Answer (score 1):

```
var position = $event.target.getBoundingClientRect();
```

var x = position.left;
var y = position.top;

```
$scope.showMenu = function(passedEventObject){
    var position = passedEventObject.target.getBoundingClientRect();
    var passedEventObjectx = position.left;
    var passedEventObjecty = position.top;
    console.log(passedEventObjectx+"=="+passedEventObjecty);
};
```